# HTTP403Forbidden when running Python's "Pattern" module

Tags: python, python-2.7

Anytime I try to run the "sort" function from python's "pattern" module. I get the follow error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/web/init.py", line 391, in open
if e.code == 403: raise HTTP403Forbidden(src=e, url=url)
pattern.web.HTTP403Forbidden
```

It's strange because my code used to run fine. Here's all I'm doing:

```
from pattern.web import sort
import json

search_terms = "chuck norris, mickey mouse"
context = "evil"

results = sort(
    terms = search_terms.split(","), 
    context = context,
    prefix = True)
print json.dumps(results)
```

anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded the daily quota of Google searches. That quota is shared among all people who use pattern with the default license key.

You need to specify your own license key, like so:

```
results = sort(
  terms = search_terms.split(","), 
  context = context,
  license = "abcd1234999999",
  prefix = True)
```

References:

- http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#sort
- http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#services